# Trouble propagating View-Model changes to the Entity Framework 6.0 entities

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to propagate my changes on my ViewModel down to the Entity Framework but am having trouble understanding just how to do that.  All of the entities in my entity framework implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Here is my VM class:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainWindowVM
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Dim dbcontext As New FootballPoolEntities
    Private _Users As ObservableCollection(Of User)
    Private _Settings As ObservableCollection(Of ScheduleSetting)
    Public Property Users As ObservableCollection(Of User)
        Get
            Return _Users
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of User))
            _Users = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Users"))
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Settings As ObservableCollection(Of ScheduleSetting)
        Get
            Return _Settings
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ScheduleSetting))
            _Settings = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Settings"))
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        'dbcontext = New FootballPoolEntities
        _Users = New ObservableCollection(Of User)(dbcontext.Users.ToList)
        _Settings = New ObservableCollection(Of ScheduleSetting)(dbcontext.ScheduleSettings.ToList)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Save()
        dbcontext.SaveChanges()
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

I understand that I need to now use a collectionchanged event to update these changes to my dbcontext, but am unclear exactly how to implement it.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was add a handler to the CollectionChanged event which added the new or deleted the removed objects from the dbcontext collection.

```
    Private Sub OnUsersCollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add Then
            For Each item In e.NewItems
                dbcontext.Users.Add(item)
            Next
        End If
        If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove Then
            For Each item In e.OldItems
                dbcontext.Users.Remove(item)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then I added a handler in my sub new()

```
AddHandler Users.CollectionChanged, AddressOf OnUsersCollectionChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we have three main layers in our application; the UI (views), the view models and the database access. The views will usually have `TextBox`es, etc. for the user to input or edit values and a Save `Button` for them to save their changes. Therefore, it is more common to save the data in response to a `Button Command` than in response to a `CollectionChanged` event.

So your view model is the place that defines the `Command` (if you're using some kind of `delegate Command`) *and* should have access to the database access layer. Therefore, it's usually a simple matter of doing something like this to save your data:

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => Save(), 
        canExecute => CanSave(AudioTrack)); }
}

...

private void Save()
{
    if (AudioTrack.IsNew) Model.AddAudioTrack(AudioTrack);
    else Model.UpdateAudioTrack(AudioTrack);
}
```